# why does calling setText() in an OnFocusChangeListener clear out the text in the view?

Tags: android, android-edittext, kotlin

When I call setText() from inside the onFocusChangeListener instead of making the field show text "hello World"  it is blank.  How can I get the text to updated when the field loses focus?

Code is in Kotlin:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus -> (view as EditText).setText("hello World") }
```

Comment: Have you considered implementing it in the class and setting the listener to this?

Comment: I cant reproduce the issue. I tried from my end. When ever edit text got focus gain/loss result the field with text "hello world"